# execute su with additional commands

Tags: macos, bash, su

I want do something like this:

```
sudo su -l <user> cd <somedir>
```

But whenever I give su additional arguments after 'user', the command returns instead of giving me an interactive shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `-l` will provide a login like interactive session
- you can try

  ```
  su -l user -c cd /some/place
  ```

  which will
- `su -l user` , then
- `cd /some/place`, then exit immediatly after cd command.

maybe you are looking for  .. ? (edit 1)

```
su -l user -c "cd /some/place ; bash -i "
```

Comment: I've tried "su -l user -c cd /some/place", but that doesn't give me a shell - it returns immediately. The "cd /some/place ; su user" variant doesn't work, because the current user does not have access rights to that directory.

Comment: @Archemar: thanks, that was nearly correct,but the -c flag was missing. It should be: 

    su -l user -c "cd /some/place ; bash -i "

Once you correct the answer I will mark it as such.